# Transforming a CSV to JSON using PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql, csv, transformation

I have a CSV file that is structured as follows:

```
Name, Place, Date
"John", "NYC", "2014-01-01, 2014-02-01"
"Bill", "LA", "2014-04-01"
"Jim", "Chicago", "2014-03-02, 2014-03-03, 2014-03-04"
```

I also have a JSON schema as follows:

```
"Name":{
    "type":"string"
    }
"Place":{
    "type":"string"
    }
"DateList":{
    "type":"array"
    "Date":{
        "type":"string"
        }
    }
```

Using functions built into PostgreSQL 9.3, is it possible to transform the CSV into a JSON matching the given schema?

Comment: Not easily. `COPY` doesn't really support CSV with variable column-lists. Why use PostgreSQL for this, it seems like a better job for a (trivial) Perl/Python/Ruby/whatever script.

Comment: If I were to use a Python script, I am guessing I would then just upload the resulting JSON to a Postgre DB. That would likely be easier.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'd do. Python, `csv` module, `psycopg2`, `json` module.